# Access denied issue when tried to copy from remote machine to local through batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Steps:

**Machine A**

---

running a batch file to connect to machine B and run a batch file(test.bat) on it

**Machine B**

---

test.bat

The copy command I am using:
`copy text.txt \\Machine A\shared folder\test.txt` (I am able to access this batch files but copy is giving access denied error)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What error do you get when you enter the copy command directly from the commandline?

Comment: it's not direct copy of a file from your local machine to remote machine. it's a copy from remote machine to your local machine operating . operating from your machine through file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your batch file located on machine B is running on machine A. Just copy the file in the batch on machine A

```
copy "\\machineb\C$\folder\file.txt" "c:\somefolder\somefile.txt"
```

C$ is the default share for admins. Use whatever sharename is appropiate.